# When express is required, is it a function or an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When I bring express into my project and create a new express app, I start with these two lines of code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

This seems to me like `express` is a function that returns the `app` object I've created. But later I am able to use `express.static()` which makes me think that `express` is an object with the method `static`.

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

When I require `express` it seems to log an object, so I'm curious how `express()` returns something if it is an object? My final guess would be that express is a function, but because this is javascript, [functions are objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944126/is-javascript-function-a-function-or-an-object-or-both) and it can have properties as well? Are any of these close to accurate?

Comment: You can see what express returns here https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/application.js

Comment: yes, in javascript, a function is an object, objects can contain functions, functions can contain objects, functions can contain functions.. etc. The prototypes will define some functionalities one have and not the other by default, different types of objets, but objects

Comment: Yes. Functions are objects and objects can have arbitrary properties. You might already know that every function has `name`, `bind`, `call`, `apply` and `prototype` properties. `static` is simply a custom property that was added "manually".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both. It is a function and it's an object - not only in a sense that every function in JavaScript is an object. It actually has some custom properties defined, like `express.static`, to use it like an normal object.

To demonstrate it let's say that you have a simple module, that exports one function like Express

```
'use strict';
function x() {
    return 'x';
}
x.a = 1;
x.b = 'b';
x.c = () => 'c';
x.d = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
module.exports = x;
```

Now when you require your module as, e.g.

```
var x = require('./x');
```

you can do:

```
console.log( x() );
```

but also:

```
console.log( x.a );
console.log( x.b );
console.log( x.c() );
console.log( x.d.a );
```