# Is this a naming convention or a function declaration

Tags: javascript, function

I am learning javascript and now started with objects and basic functions. I came across this type of code and was wondering what exactly is this

```
var stringFunction = function(){};

stringFunction.test1 = function(){
  console.log("Test 1");
}
```

does test1 is a part of stringFunction or just a naming convention.Thanks in advance

Comment: Neither, it's a property definition. Functions in JS are objects.

Comment: but on doing a typeof for stringFunction it returns as a function not an object

Comment: @Srikanth: yes... they're "weird". But if weirdness and special cases scare you then probably Javascript is not your language :-D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Function really an Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941729/is-function-really-an-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `test1()` is a property (function type) of the `stringFunction` var.
So you defined a function in a function object.

You can use it by invoking `stringFunction.test1();` as you can invoke the outer function : `stringFunction();`

```
var stringFunction = function(){console.log("Test stringFunction")};

stringFunction.test1 = function(){
    console.log("Test 1");
}

stringFunction();
stringFunction.test1();
```

OUTPUT :

> Test stringFunction
>
> Test 1

Comment: And we can still call stringFunction() and it will work as it was working before?

Comment: @Mohit Bhardwaj  Yes. These are two distinct usable objects.

Comment: Thanks @davidxxx :)

Answer (score 1):

`function` instances are sort of "weird" in Javascript as they are objects but their `typeof` is `"function"` and not `"object"`.

They can however have properties added and accessed using either the syntax `f.x` or `f["x"]`. Your code simply adds a property to a `function` object (the value of the property is also a function, but that is irrelevant).

Comment: oh okay, but when you console log an object you will be able to see all the properties and other prototypes associated with the object, whereas for this instance i was only able to see the function associated with the property.

Comment: @Srikanth: indeed `Function` instances are quite strange... for example `Object.keys(f)` will return the names of all properties you added (but not predefined properties like for example `"name"`). Another weirdness is that `f.length` for example returns 0, not `undefined` and cannot be set.

Answer (score 0):

in JavaScript every function is a Function Object. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function. In you sample the code create a property 'test1' on object stringFunction. The new property is itsealf a Function Object.